# What Version of the Sketch did I leave on there?

Tags: programming

Is there a way to "ask" the Arduino what sketch was compiled on it?

There are several versions of the sketch and I need to see which version the Arduino has been running.

Comment: No, but if you really want to there might be a way. First of all, you should add a version number (text or a number) into your sketch. When there is output to the serial monitor or a display, then show the name and the version. Next, make a header and write in comments which version of the arduino ide is used. About your problem: with avrdude you can retrieve the binary code. When you also know which version of the arduino ide was used to compile the sketch, then you can compare the binary versions of the sketch, until you find the right one.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to store the desired information in your sketch.

```
#define VERSION F("0.01 4-Apr-2019")

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.print(F("Test Sketch V"));
   Serial.println(VERSION); 
}

void loop() { 
}
```

Of course any other way might work as well:

- Only print it, if at reset a test button is pressed
- Check for a Serial command and respond the version info.
- Don't print it, but use avrdude and a programmer to read the FLASH memory and search it for the version string. (Similar to jot's comment above)

Answer (score 0):

If you have not set the flash protection bits you can read back the contents of the program memory. See https://www.evilmadscientist.com/2011/avr-basics-reading-and-writing-flash-contents/

By reading back the first pages you can then compare with the different versions of the sketch (hex file) and determine which version is on the device. The first pages are the different ISR vectors and should be unique for the sketches.

Cheers!